# Проблема с авторизацией Steam Openid

Tags: php, steam-web-api, openid

Возникла проблема при которой при очень частых запросов ломается авторизация через OpenID к Steam платформе.

Использую открытую библиотеку LightOpenID (https://github.com/iignatov/LightOpenID).

При частых запросах авторизации Steam перестает корректно отвечать и взамен этому отвечает подобное сообщение:

> Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   "http://steamcommunity.com/openid/" on this server
>
> Reference ***

Возможно причина не в частых запросах, но как я понимаю Steam блокирует дальнейшие запросы и отвечает подобным сообщением, вместо OpenID данных.

Как это исправить? буду рад любой помощи или хотя бы наводки на правильное решение. Может быть стоит менять библиотеку? и на какую лучше всего?

Заранее большое спасибо.